# Computer Sometimes Hangs During Startup and Always Hangs After Sleeping

Tags: boot, cpu, computer-building, debug

I just built a new rig (full specs and BIOS snapshots at bottom) and I'm having a problem with it experiencing what appears to be random CPU hangs during startup.

My board is an MSI B450I Mini-ITX and it has 4 "EZ Debug" LED's. They are CPU, DRAM, VGA, and BOOT. (I am not the most experienced PC builder so I apologize if I'm providing unnecessary OR insufficient information.) When it fails to boot, the CPU EZ debug light is on. When this happens, there is no output to the monitor or the keyboard or mouse (they don't light up). There is one exception here, when I put the computer to sleep and try to resume Windows the mouse (and probably keyboard but can't say for sure) will receive power but the monitor still receives nothing and the computer will not boot (CPU EZ debug light on again).

The computer fails to resume 100% of the time after being put to sleep and after the power supply has been disconnected and reconnected. Other than that, it seems pretty random with failures about 1/2 to 2/3 of the time. I haven't actually recorded any tests, this is just my feeling after working with it for a week. Basically I have to start it, hold the power button to shut it off, and then repeat once or twice before it takes. I have not had it randomly shut off once I've had it up and running (maybe once at the very beginning before I even had Windows 10 installed, but really couldn't say) and It has run for days at a time.

I just uninstalled, cleaned, and reinstalled the CPU. I'm 99.99% sure it's irrelevant, but I had to modify the heat sink by chopping off the AMD badge that sticks out on the fan portion if you're familiar with the Ryzen 5 heat sinks (google images will show you what I'm talking about).

Thank you very much for reading this and any information you are able to provide.

Complete Hardware

- MSI B450I
- AMD Ryzen 5 2600
- Ballistix Sport LT 16GB (8GBx2) DDR4 2666
- CORSAIR SF450
- GIGABYTE GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
- Running Windows 10 on a Samsung 850 EVO 500GB SSD

***2018-12-27 Update***:
Initially, the BIOS was 3 months old. I performed a BIOS update to a version released just a few weeks ago and the problem persists. Although, when testing the problem a few minutes ago, I did successfully boot back up after putting the computer to sleep. This contradicts where I said it fails 100% of time when put to sleep. To my knowledge, that's the only time that has worked. I got all excited and tried it again after a restart and it failed.

[Initial BIOS Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OPKq.jpg)

[Updated BIOS Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVGeg.jpg)

Comment: Have you checked for, found, and installed ALL of the latest drivers and firmware from the manufacturers?

Comment: Thanks for giving this some thought @music2myear. In short, no. I have installed the latest drivers for the MOBO and graphics card, but not updated the MOBO BIOS. I was avoiding that to leave it for last since I've never done that before and don't want to screw something up. But I do know that I am one version behind on the BIOS according to MSI's website. I am going to update the original post to include a snapshot of the BIOS in case that flags anything else.

Comment: Update the BIOS. It rarely causes problems, it's usually rather simple, just involving running and executable and restarting the computer when prompted, and it can fix problems. Sleep-related problems are usually caused by driver problems. However, you should also check the Event viewer to see what is happening around the crashes, if there are bugchecks or memory dumps that can point you in the right direction.

Comment: @music2myear, sorry I vanished for a few days. You know, Christmas. So I did actually go ahead and update the BIOS back on the 22nd and you were right: easy peasy. Unfortunately, no dice. The automatic reboot the BIOS update performed even failed to take. From what I remember, I turned it on and off about 4 times to finally get it to boot. Then I left it running for 5 days while I was gone and returned to it still on (further illustrating the problem is only experienced at boot). I'm gonna update the post with the BIOS info in case someone doesn't read comments. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Those additional symptoms sound like possible hardware issues. Since you just built this, can you exchange any parts?

Comment: @music2myear where would you start? MOBO?